# Calling function in a php file and passing JavaScript variables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a file.php and inside a function.
Javascript Side, I use Ajax.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "file.php",
  data: {param1: params1, param2: params2...},
  complete: function(data){
   /* code */
  }
});
```

Now in the file file.php, a function login exists. My question how can I call the function login ? Thanks.

```
function ft_login($login, $password) {
    $u = new KVObject();
    $u->collection = "users";
    $u->loadFormArray(["login" => $login, "password" => $password]);
    if ($u->obj_id == null)
        return ["ERROR" => "Bad creditial"];
    if ($u->status == "blocked")
        return ["ERROR" => "Account need to be activated"];

    $token = md5(time());
    $_SESSION[$token] = $u->dataObject;
    return ["token" => $token, "user" => $u->dataObject];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The whole php file is executed. So if you call ft_login inside file.php it gets executed. You can pass your parameters to that function.

Dont forget to json_decode your parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass another parameter instructing the PHP code what to do

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "file.php",
    data: {request: 'login', password:userid, password:password},
    complete: function(data){
    }
});
```

And then in the `file.php` PHP code

```
<?php
function ft_login($login, $password) {

    . . .

}

if ( isset($_POST['request'] && $_POST['request'] == 'login' ) {
    if ( isset($_POST['login'], $_POST['password']) ) {
        $result = ft_login($_POST['login'], $_POST['password']);

        // do whatever with $result
    }
}
```